# How do I turn this commonly used javascript code into a plugin?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

**Overview**

I am developing a Wordpress based website that allows a visitor to upload images at a few different places on the page. I have (after a LOT of trial and error) got some working code but, as the code only differs slightly between each 'upload' area, I thought about trying to make it re-usable in the form of a 'plugin'.

**My Background**

I am a self-taught programmer so I am prone to lots of mistakes and doing things in completely illogical ways plus writing a thousand lines of code when one line would have sufficed.

**History of the Problem (please skip this section to see the code below)**

I thought I would include a bit of history so that I don't fall foul of the [X-Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I have 4 places on the webpage that visitors can upload to the site. 3 of these are image uploads that should allow the visitor to also 'crop' the image. I'm using the jQuery plugins [plupload](http://www.plupload.com/) and [jcrop](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html) in order to provide the functionality.

Initially I attempted to write the code in a way that the page included relevant code in the DOM at execution time. In order to have multiple plupload instances on the same page I created one "dynamic variable" and then called the code like this...

```
var dynamicPartOfVar = "imageUploadAreaOne";
imageManipulationObject["imageUploader"+dynamicPartOfVar] = new plupload.Uploader(plupload_init);
```

This worked (of a fashion) but I found out that if the code is in the DOM then it isn't being cache'd by the browser. So I then went down the route of having a separate js file for each upload area and 'including' them and passing in the relevant variables with:

```
wp_localize_script("imageUploadAreaOne", "inputVar", $relevantVariableArray);
wp_enqueue_script("imageUploadAreaOne");
```

However, I quickly realised that if I could 'pass in' different variables to the same file I could make just one set of code and (for instance) pass a variable called "allowCropping" which would enable/disable jCrop etc.

**Issue**

I have code such as (just an example):

```
var isAdmin = inputVar.isAdmin;
var notAdmin = inputVar.notAdmin;
var thisUser = inputVar.thisUser;
var ajaxurl = inputVar.ajaxurl;
imageManipulationObject["imageUploader"+dynamicPartOfVar] = new plupload.Uploader(plupload_init);   
imageManipulationObject["ProgressLoader"+dynamicPartOfVar] = $('#ProgressLoader'+dynamicPartOfVar).percentageLoader({width: 170, height: 170, progress:0.0});

/* **************************** */
// HIDE CROPPING DIV WHEN USER SELECTS A DIFFERENT IMAGE
/* **************************** */
$('.imageSelection').on('click', function() {   
    closeCropWindow();
});
$('.imageThumb').on('click', function() {   
    closeCropWindow();
});
```

HTML Example

```
<div id="mainCropDivID<?php echo $this->dynamicPartOfVar; ?>">
    <div class="outerCropDiv">

    <div id="innerCropDivID<?php echo $this->dynamicPartOfVar; ?>" class="innerCropDiv">
    <img class="croppingImage" id="croppingImageID<?php echo $this->dynamicPartOfVar; ?>" alt="Cropping Image" src="<?php echo $currentURL; ?>"/>

    <div class="JTcentreDiv">
    <form id="cropimg<?php echo $this->dynamicPartOfVar; ?>" name="cropimg" method="post" action="<?php echo $getPartOfURL; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" id="x_<?php echo $this->dynamicPartOfVar; ?>" name="x">
    <input type="hidden" id="y_<?php echo $this->dynamicPartOfVar; ?>" name="y">
    <input type="hidden" id="w_<?php echo $this->dynamicPartOfVar; ?>" name="w">
    <input type="hidden" id="h_<?php echo $this->dynamicPartOfVar; ?>" name="h">
    <input type="hidden" name="typeOfImage" value="<?php echo $this->typeOfImage; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" id="imageIDtoCrop<?php echo $this->dynamicPartOfVar; ?>" name="imageIDtoCrop" value="">

    <input id="performCropButton<?php echo $this->dynamicPartOfVar; ?>" type="submit" value="Crop Image">
    </form>
    </div>

    </div><!-- @end #innerCropDivID -->  
    </div><!-- @end .outerCropDiv --> 
    <div style="clear:both;">&nbsp;</div>   

</div> <!-- @end #mainCropDivID -->
```

Assuming that wrapping this all up in a 'plugin' is the way to go. How would I go about doing that? I want to be able to pass in variables into the plugin including several DOM elements (i.e. I would like to pass to the plugin the div that holds the image that needs to be cropped, the div that holds the preview of the image, the div that holds the currently uploaded image etc). Plus other variables such as whether to allow 'cropping' or not.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: So you want to bind the plugin to the main image elements? How does the html structure look (preview, upload div etc)?

Comment: @Johan I have added an example of some of the HTML. It is all in separate functions to draw the elements that are required. For example, a function to draw the Open Crop Window button which is only needed if the 'crop' functionality is available etc. Hope that helps. If you need more info please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need to create a new JS file (that is going to be your plugin)
the piece of code necessary for this is

```
(function ($) {
$.fn.myFunctionPlugin= function (options) {
var defaults = {
    };
    var settings = $.extend(true, {}, defaults, options);
}

function dosomthing()
{
//CODE HERE
}
} (jQuery));
```

Add a reference to the plugin on your page(in the same way you add reference to jquery or any other third party js)

```
<script src="...Reference" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

add another script segment on the same page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var options = {actionToPerform:"...",//This may be a controller action performed
 idcalss="....." //Class of the item on the view you want to pass in}

 $('.someclass').jsFunction(options);
 });
```

PS: Please refer to the book JQuery in action second edition from page 205

Reference for a simple jquery plugin writing: [jquery plugin example](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/)

Comment: Hi Jack, thanks for the answer. I'm struggling with seeing how you are linking the function call on the page $('.someclass'.jsFunction(options) to $.fn.myFunctionPlugin ? How does it know where myFunctionPlugin is? Apologies if I'm missing something obvious here. Thanks.

Comment: because you have added the reference to your plugin in the page where you want to use it. Basically it is the same as jquery when you want to use it you put the reference to jquery on the page and then you write your javascript code including jquery functions. So replace jquery with your plugin to understand how it works. it can even be easy if you use the source file of jquery and then do a small js function to change like a colour you will understand it better that way

Comment: Actually, you should use `$.fn.extend({'myFunctionPlugin':function(){[...]}});` or `$.fn.prototype.myFunctionPlugin=function(){[...]}`. That way works, but this one is a bit more correct.

Comment: And am I right in thinking it is possible to call other plugins from within a plugin (i.e. I can use plupload / jcrop etc just the same but within the encapsulation of a plugin?)

Comment: but you are already doing it when you use JQuery, but if it is a plugin you wrote for your application that would be a very bad coding Refer to SOLID Principles