# How do I turn this JavaScript into a plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have looked through the old answers, and found one that seems to be what I want to do [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25928807/how-do-i-turn-this-commonly-used-javascript-code-into-a-plugin). Although I don't fully understand and not sure what is wrong and what I should be doing in the next step. [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/revzephyr/b42vn2nh/76/)

Thanks in advance

```
//Put inside HTML
$(function () {
    $('#s_table').setups({
        //please name table ID as "s_table"
        "scrollY_h":"200px",
        "s_empty":"search not found",
    });
});

//xxx.js
(function (a) {
    a.fn.s_table= function (setups) {
        var scrollY = "",
            s_empty = "";}

{
my function here?
}
})(JQuery);
```

Comment: There are lots of tutorials and other resources on the web on how to author jQuery plugins. Suggest you study some of those

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good tutorial on how to create a JQuery plugin:

http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

Comment: I found the same webpage 5 mins ago, and reading away. +1 for giving a useful link! Thanks